# Is there a way to undo a comment upvote?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm reading through the comments to an answer, and I would have sworn one of them had an upvote, which now has dissappeared. I distinctly remember, because I found the upvote totally unfair.

Is there a way to undo? I only see an upvote button.

Comment: It would be nice if we could, but the people who run the site are very adamantly in favor of locking-in erroneous votes for some reason.

Comment: @endolith - It appears you still can change your mind, but don't wait too long.

Comment: Yep, you can revert accidental clicks, but you can't revert if you later realize your vote was factually wrong

Comment: The did not used to let you undo comment votes at all @endolith, but you probably remember that. Comments are second rate citizens and are mostly not liked by the SE overlords.

Comment: @Kortuk: I have no problem with moving the content of comments into the answers and deleting them.  Anything to improve the signal to noise ratio is good.  It's just frustrating to learn about a topic, realize your votes were erroneous, and not be able to change them, and the only justification is "well if we let people change their votes they might abuse it or something".

Comment: @endolith I never meant to imply I agree with such a policy but they do not ever want to make comments a meaningful part of the site.

Answer (score 4):

You can undo an upvote (probably it was mine, i missclicked) but it displays a popup that you can't upvote again.

[image]

But nice catch!

Comment: Ah, it looks like you have to do it within a certain, short time. I tried it for a comment I upvoted this morning and it doesn't work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @stevenvh NP :)

Comment: It could have been yours, it was a question you also answered.

Comment: @stevenvh I think about opamps, and it was the comment by CyberMen :) I missclicked. But it gave me the chance for some freehand circle, which I always appreciate

Comment: The feature announcement on MSO is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032.  The certain, short time is 60 seconds, and you can't navigate away from the page during that time.